# Extracting data from a text file and writing it elsewhere

Tags: tcl

How can I read a file and put the elements in it to a list and write the contents to other file?

the file contents are

```
this is my house and it is very good
this is my village and it is the best
```

`good` and `best` has to be repeated 10 times.

help me if possible

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like that?

```
set fi [open "filename"]
set fo [open "outputfile" w]
while {[gets $fi line]!=-1} {
  if {$line!=""} {
    for {set i 0} {$i<10} {incr i} {
      puts $fo $line
    }
  }
}
close $fi
close $fo
```

Comment: You should never do `while {![eof $fi]} {set line [gets $fi];...}`. Use this instead: `while {[gets $fi line] != -1} {...}`. `[eof]` only returns true **after** you have tried to read past the end of the file, so you go through one extra iteration of the while loop after reading the last line.

Comment: @Glenn: Thank you for the hint. I will adapt my answer.

Comment: what if good = 10 and best=20, if both of these are contained in some file , and that file has to be read ones and the output should be as follows/////////// I am good-10 am best-20 I

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear.

Do you mean the lines containing "good" or "best" need to be repeated 10 times?

```
set fin [open infile r]
set fout [open outfile w]
while {[gets $fin line] != -1} {
    switch -glob -- $line {
        *good* -
        *best* {
            for {set i 1} {$i <= 10} {incr i} {
                puts $fout $line
            }
        }
        default {
            # what to do for lines NOT containing "good" or "best"?
        }
    }
}
close $fin
close $fout
```

If you mean the actual words need to be repeated 10 times:

```
while {[gets $fin line] != -1} {
    puts $fout [regsub -all {\y(good|best)\y} $line {& & & & & & & & & &}]
}
```

An example for that regsub command:

```
set str "these goods are good; that bestseller is the best"
puts [regsub -all {\y(good|best)\y} $str {& & &}]
# prints: these goods are good good good; that bestseller is the best best best
```

**Update**

Based on your comments, you might want:

```
array set values {good 10 best 20}
while {[gets $fin line] != -1} {
    regsub -all {\y(good|best)\y} $line {&-$values(&)} line
    puts $fout [subst -nobackslashes -nocommands $line]
}
```

Comment: what if good = 10 and best=20, if both of these are contained in some file , and that file has to be read ones and the output should be as follows/////////// I am good-10 am best-20 I

Comment: only the words good and bad are to be taken out and repeated 10 times and 20 times respectively//// the prefix should be I am good-10 am best-20 I, similarly if there are multiple such lines then the prefix should start with I am good-10 am best-20 I am next line extracted and so on,